Why Symfony does not create sequence upon migration execution?
The problem was automatic ID generation for new records in postgresql entities despite declaring strategy as AUTO in GeneratedValue attribute - it did not generate the ids.
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy: "AUTO")]
    #[ORM\Column]
    protected $id = null;


To fix this, you have to set a type for an id column:
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy: "AUTO")]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    protected $id = null;

Create new migration, execute and after execution you should notice a new sequence in postgresql database sequences.
